# mat-icon não está funcionando

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estou iniciando em Angular e agora estou tentando fazer meu primeiro projeto. Estou tentando usar o o Angular Material, mas logo na barra de navegação, não consigo usar o ícone de menu no botão. Tudo que é preciso importar ou adicionar ao projeto, conforme documentação, já foi feito.

Assim está o HTML do botão:

```
<button mat-icon-button> <mat-icon fontIcon="menu"></mat-icon> </button>
```

Comment: Supondo que as dependências tenham sido adequadamente referenciadas, trata-se de um erro de sintaxe. Tente isso `<button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>`

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o seu ícone esteja errado:

```
<button type="button" mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

Além disso, certifique-se de importar o módulo, conforme documentação [Button|API](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api) e [Icon|API](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api):

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

 
imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).